# Bulk-Update Custom Posts

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, bulk

I have the following code in my functions.php file that I'm using to create a custom meta_key called 'spec_wp' (which is based on the value of an ACF repeater):

```
add_filter('acf/save_post', 'convert_spec_to_standard_wp_meta', 20);

function convert_spec_to_standard_wp_meta($post_id) {

  $meta_key = 'spec_wp';

  delete_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key);

  $saved_values = array();

  if (have_rows('specs', $post_id)) {
    while (have_rows('specs', $post_id)) {
      the_row();
      $specval = get_sub_field('spec_value');

      if (isset($saved_values[$specval])) {
        continue;
      }

      add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $specval, false);

      $saved_values[$specval] = $specval;

    } 
  } 
}
```

The code works as intended, but spec_wp is only created for a post when that post is updated from its edit screen.

Does anyone know of a way to bulk-update posts so that I don't have to go through and update them one by one? I have 1,700 posts that need this meta_key, so updating them all manually isn't really an option.

I've tried using the 'bulk actions' > 'edit' > 'update' feature in on the 'all posts' page but it doesn't seem to work.

I've also tried changing the action to 'acf/init' and just 'init', but that didn't work either.